# Wondering why a couple of my suggested tag edits were rejected?

Tags: discussion, editing, tags

Over the last two days I've made a number of tag edits in the hope of improving the excerpts a bit, mainly with the goal of format consistency.

Initially, I was editing them mostly to make them start with 'Questions about.. ?'. Then I found that the statement of the purpose of the tag could also be consistent. Combining both, I concluded that the most versatile, least obstructive and best format for consistency is:

> **Questions about** x, a letter of the alphabet. X is the third from last letter in the alphabet. **Ask anything** related to designing graphics with x.

In a more descriptive form:

> **Questions about** [the subject], [very brief description of the subject]. [Something about the subject that's relevant to graphic design, or more brief description of the subject]. **Ask anything related to** [actions commonly taken with this subject relative to graphic design].

Some examples of my successful recent edits, in many cases I was able to keep most of the original text:

[patterns](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/patterns)

<sup>Questions about patterns, usually a repeating unit of shape, and often a small, repeating and tile-able element. Most patterns are based on repetition and periodicity while others use magnification and scaling. Ask anything related to designing or altering patterns.</sup>

[resize](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resize)

<sup>Questions about the action of resizing, a transformation that either enlarges or shrinks an object. Ask anything about resizing graphics in a graphic design software.</sup>

[adobe-fireworks](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-fireworks)

<sup>Questions about Fireworks, Adobe's bitmap and vector graphics editor; widely used for web and interface design. Ask anything related to designing graphics with Fireworks.</sup>

[images](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/images)

<sup>Questions that include methods for creating, editing, manipulating and enhancing images. Ask anything related to the design of images.</sup>

There's no perfect template, but you should be able to see what I'm getting at. There are nearly 20 more edits like these, but there's no point posting them all. You can sleuth my profile if you want to see the rest.

Now, what I'm wondering, is why the same users who accepted most of my edits, chose to reject a few. I don't see a difference between the 23 accepted edits and the 2 rejected edits.

[**Here**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/14834) I edited the [photo-editing](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photo-editing) tag. I kept most of the original text, just trying to adjust it to fit the format I've shown above.

[**Here**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/14799) I edited the [workflow](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/workflow) tag. I changed a lot of the excerpt, mainly because most of it was too descriptive, and was already in the wiki.

The first edit in the list was rejected for the reasons:

> This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.

and

> Don't like the "ask anything about" bit.

The second edit in the list was rejected for the reason:

> This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.

I don't really understand any of these rejections. I spend a bit of time doing these edits, and I put real thought in. Therefore, I would like some more explanation as to why these edits should be rejected. I don't do it for the measly 2 rep points, I do it to help. Rejected voluntary help feels like time completely wasted. Also, rejected edits appear to be permanent, and I consider them unnecessary stains on my record.

Please consider these edits again, with the new information I've given about the intent for the structure and format, and let me know why they should or shouldn't have been rejected. As far as I know, the decision cannot be reversed, but I would like to set the record straight for peace of mind.

Comment: Your workflow tag edit was rejected because I thought brendan's was better and as you already stated more descriptive.

Comment: I would suggest trying not to reject edits, but (if possible) improve them instead. For example, [this one](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/14834) was really easy to change. If the "ask anything about" was not considered good enough, it was just a matter of removing that line. Rejecting a tag throws away very valuable effort, these edits have been great, and I think any improvements (shortening descriptions included) should definitely be encouraged.

Comment: I only caught an update once and I approved the one I saw (technically I guess two Wiki and Excerpt). Thanks Dom! Mr E. Solved

Comment: I have never rejected a tag edit. As @Yisela says - it is usually valuable; both in human effort, as a process and as an "organic" improvement exercise.  We have edit history so nothing is really in vain.

Comment: I applaud you for attracting attention to this - I think it is good to share some views on it. No, I did not think you did this to "catch" anyone out :) But airing views can only be a good thing.